# I have issue in responsive menu

Tags: html, css

I have issue in responsive menu.if you shrink the browser and click the menu image.it is not coming in orderly.check this check the link.  http://vkacademy.in/res/ what is the property I need to use.  In mobile.css file I have used class common.I want to know  what is the property shall I need to use additional in common class to bring the menu properly .I know to use pixel only.kindly give me the answer in pixel.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#mob_btn').click(function(e) {
        $('.common').slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="logo"><img src="image/logo.png"  border="0" width="357" height="107"/></div><!--endoflogo-->
<div id="logo1"><a href="#">join as tutor or Institutue</a></div><!--endoflogo1-->
<div class="menu_btn"><img id="mob_btn" src="image/menu.png"/></div>
<div id="menu">
<div class="common"><a href="#">About us</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">Department</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">Facilities</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">library</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">Event</a></div>
</div><!--endofmenu-->
</div><!--endofwrapper-->
    my default.css
    body
    {
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    }
    #wrapper
    {
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    }

    #logo
    {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    }
    #logo1
    {
    width:400px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:50px;
    background-color:#FF00FF;
    }

    #menu
    {
    width:1000px;
    height:45px;
    float:left;
    }

    .common
    {
    width:200px;
    height:42px;
    padding-top:8px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
    }

    #content
    {
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    }
    .menu_btn 
    {
        display: none;
    }

   **In mobile.css**
    @media only screen and (max-width:530px)
    {
    #wrapper
    {
    width:260px;
    background-repeat:repeat;

    }

    #logo
    {
    width:260px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#FFFF00;
    }

    #logo img
    {
    width:260px;
    text-align:center;
    }

    #logo1
    {
    width:160px;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:50px;
    height:auto;    
    }

    .menu_btn
    {
    width:260px;
    height:48px;
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    }

    .common
    {
    width:260px;
    display:none;

    }

    .common
    {
    width:260px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jorge9200 mentioned, you need to know about media queries first. [Here is a link for easier understanding](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/).

a basic/ quicker eg:

```
/* Mobile first queries */

/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) { your own CSS for this particular screen size }

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {your own CSS for this particular screen size}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {your own CSS for this particular screen size}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {your own CSS for this particular screen size}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {your own CSS for this particular screen size}
```

The above media queries are pre-defined for major screen sizes. You can either use them and write your CSS for each of your classes and IDs
or 
you could use responsive CSS framework like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for a quicker development.

Answer (score 0):

If you want responsive design you will need to do it yourself by using:

html file:

```
<div id="menu">
<div class="common"><a href="#">About us</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">Department</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">Facilities</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">library</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">Event</a></div>
</div><!--endofmenu-->
```

CSS file:

```
/* There are 5 buttons on the menu so: */
.common{width:20%}

/* Then I make the responsive*/
@media (min-width: 600px, max-width: 768px){
#menu{width:600px;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px, max-width: 900px){
#menu{width:768px;}
}
```

(...)

for example, on a css file.

Comment: sure I am learning. can you help me with the menu problem. what property I need to add in common class

Comment: You can use bootstrap library, it provides a easy way to make the responsive design. If you dont want to, you can add clases to common divs and parent one, which will modify each width in diferents @media

Comment: I added to my answer a possible solution, without bootstrap.